# How to declare/use extern map in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, extern

I'm not very used and don't really understand the use of global variables in c++, and cannot manage to solve a problem here, although I'm nearly sure I'm using the declarations the right way.
I've got an unordered map, which contains params from a file. This is working fine, I've outputted the contents, everything ok.
But I would like this map to be available everywhere in my program, so that I don't have to pass it as an argument every time, hence the use of global variable.
I've a little typedef :

```
typedef tr1::unordered_map<string,float> unmap;
```

then the function to read the parameters:

```
unmap readParameters(string filename);
```

then the global scope declaration (everything outside the main of course, although in the same file, I still don't have any headers):

```
extern unmap params;
```

The affectation is made in the main() function:

```
unmap params=readParameters(inputfile_name);
```

(Note: I tried with and without the "unmap", but same error).
And I've got a function displayInformation() to display its contents in which I use my map "params":

```
for (unmap::iterator it=params.begin();it!=params.end();it++){
    cout<<it->first<<" = "<<it->second<<endl;
}
```

But g++ moans then :

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_params", referenced from:
      _main in loca.o
      displayInformation()     in loca.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [loca] Error 1
```

So how should I declare/use this to be able to see it from any function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c i think that is explained there in detail.

Comment: Thank you I figured it out! I already read this post but it seems that i misplaced the declaration of the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `extern` declaration tells the compiler that you have **defined** the variable elsewhere. The error you are seeing is down to the fact that you have not defined the variable anywhere. You need to add a line like the following:

```
unmap params;
```

However, in your case, you can just remove the `extern` declaration as it is unnecessary if the global variable is only used in the same file it is defined. Typically you put an `extern` declaration in a header file when you define the global variable in one .cpp file, and then use it in another. `extern` is essentially saying "there is a variable somewhere named X of type Y", but it does not actually define that variable.

Comment: "not defined the variable anywhere". I feel so dumb, I changed the name of my constants in the source file, which was why the header wasn't matching the source file.

Answer (score 3):

the best practice is to make a header file and call it global.h or something else. Everywhere you need your global variable you include the header file.
In the header file you add the following code:

```
//global.h
#include<map>
extern std::unordered_map<string, float> unmap;
```

the next step is to define the global variable that can you do for example in the main.cpp

```
//main.cpp
#include"global.h"

//definition of the global variable (just once)
std::unordered_map<string, float> unmap;

int main() {
unmap = readParameters("fileName");
}
```

now you can use the global map everywhere you include the file global.h

I hope that was what you have looked for